# Is it OK to have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribuable installed several time (same year / CPU / version)?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, visual-studio, redistributable

If I go to `Programs` > `Programs and features` on my computer, I have `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribuable` item installed several times, for the same year and for the same CPU target (x86 or x64). Sometimes, even version is the same (only install date is different).

[image]

Is this OK or, should I uninstall the duplicates (and only keep latest version ?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for having multiple copies of same versions of VC++ Redistributables, they provide same libraries for the programs which use them.

However, It's okay to install multiple versions of VC++ as their libraries are different and many programs need specific version of those.

You can uninstall the duplicate copies of same version.

*Note: It is possible that there is one copy of actual libraries on your system and there are two entries in programs' list (The latest entry might have replace the old files). If you like, you can uninstall all version of VC++, and install the fresh copy of those (all versions 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 & 2015; both x64 & x86).*

Comment: "There is no need for having multiple copies of same versions of VC++ Redistributables, they provide same libraries for the programs which use them." This isn't true, each version references a different version of the dll and each version is independent of one another and a program can target one or multiple versions

Comment: @Ramhound You didn't read it right. I wrote "There is no need for having multiple copies of SAME versions". I am not saying "There is no need for having MULTIPLE versions". The same exact version provide same libraries and different ones provide different libraries.